# Кнопка показать / скрыть текст

Tags: javascript, html

Сделал кнопку показать / скрыть текст, но как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "скрыть текст", экран возвращался к тому месту где была нажата кнопка "показать текст" (сейчас экран остается там где была кнопка скрыть при открытом тексте)?

Код html:

```
<span id="show-more">ЧИТАТЬ ПОДРОБНЕЕ</span>
<span id="show-less">Скрыть</span>
```

Код js:

```
$('#show-more-content').hide();

$('#show-more').click(function(){
$('#show-more-content').show();
$('#show-less').show();
$(this).hide();
});

$('#show-less').click(function(){
$('#show-more-content').hide();
$('#show-more').show();
     $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: имеется ввиду прокрутка страницы?

Comment: Да, прокрутка назад к кнопке показать

Comment: можно попробовать использовать [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовал  jQuery

```js
$('#show-more-content').hide();

$('#show-more').click(function() {
  $('#show-more-content').show();
  $('#show-less').show();
  $(this).hide();
});

$('#show-less').click(function() {
  $('#show-more-content').hide();
  $('#show-more').show();
  $(this).hide();

  $("#show-more")[0].scrollIntoView();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
-------------
<span id="show-more">ЧИТАТЬ ПОДРОБНЕЕ</span> *** ***
<span id="show-less">Скрыть</span> -------------
```